# An Introductory Integration Problem That I Need Help with

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am just getting started on learning integration, and I am getting stuck on a problem.

**The problem is:**
A bug starts at the location $x = 12$ on the x-axis at 1 pm
walks along the axis with the velocity shown in Fig. 6. How far does the
bug travel between 1 pm and 3 pm, and where is the bug at 3 pm? [This is the image of fig. 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyyTk.png)

[image]

I tried to find the area under the function by taking the area of the rectangle and triangle, but that does not seem to work - especially because the function goes below the x-axis.

Any help on what I should do?

Comment: The problem didn't have any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use rectangle area, and that triangle formed by the velocity-time line between 2 pm and 3 pm seems to be symmetric so because of that the ant seems to be back in the place where it used to be on 2 pm, so you dont need to account for the triangle area

Comment: What would that make the answer?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Do I now just do 1(10)? How does the negative factor in? Does the starting at 12 part of the question make a difference?

Comment: First you calculate the distance that the ant travelled (the triangle area eliminate each other because of symmetry, so dont worry about negative factor),because the ant walk along the x-axis that mean it doesnt move up/down so you can just add $x$ (the starting point)with your distance to get where the ant is on 3pm

Comment: Thanks! So that would find me where he is at 3, but how do I figure out how much he walked?

Comment: Use the rectangle area as i said, distance is area under graph of velocity and time axis